# Databind not updating after I use a WebClient to fetch some data

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-mobile, webclient

I'm fairly new to Windows Mobile Development (.net framework as well) and I have been trying to figure out a solution for this problem I'm having for quite some time:

1 - I have a ViewModel, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged that contains my list of people:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> listOfPeople;
```

2 - I am databinding listOfPeople to a listbox;

3 - I created some dummy data in my MainPage.xaml.cs and it updates the listbox.

4 - The problem is when I try to update people info from a rss that I download: For every person object I call an its Person.updateData() method. The method fetches some info from an rss feed:

```
internal void updateData()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(sourceUrl));

        }


        void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Parse the data: 
              ...

            //Try to update:

                updateAge(age);
                updateAddress(Address);                
            }

        }
```

And the values are updated in the class but not in the UI.
 After I searched I found the handler operates in a diff thread, and thats probably the problem.
 I tried

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { updateSeason(season); });
```

but didnt work.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Do you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Another thread probably is not a reason because `DownloadStringCompleted` event handler is running in thread in which `WebClient` was created (in this case probably UI thread).

This may be too obvious question, but have you generated [INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event in your ViewModel when you are trying to update UI?

Comment: Hi, thx for the help, but yeah I have done that.
The UI is updated when I call to change the values anywhere except inside the wc_DownloadStringCompleted. I have tested it changing the values in the modelviewer, in the main class, in the own Person class and it works. Only when I try to do it inside the wc_DownloadStringCompleted it doesnt update the UI.